# Variable hero image in django

Tags: css, django

In a django webapp, I have a page with a hero image.  This happens mostly because there's some CSS (in a .css file) that contains a class called `.hero-image` with a `background-image:` tag with `url("...")` value.

Now I'd like to have the image controlled by some logic: something in the world leads to a database lookup that decides whether to use image `one.png`, `two.png`, etc.

The only reasonable way I see to do this is to move the `.hero-image` CSS block from the CSS file to be inline CSS served each time the page is served.  (This at least seems more efficient than making the .css file be served dynamically instead of from static and so changing all the time.)

This seems like something that is likely a relatively common need, so it bothers me that I've not found documentation on it.

Am I on target or is there a better way to approach this?

### Update

I'm showing here the code I eventually wrote to solve this.  I'm also accepting the response from @melvyn, which is not quite what I asked but includes answers to quite a lot of what I should have asked).

In my `urls.py`, I started doing things like this:

```
path('nous', views.AssoView.as_view(template_name='asso/qui-sommes-nous.html',
                                    hero_image="asso_tn/happy-folks-1000.jpg",
                                    hero_title="Qui sommes-nous ?"),
     name='qui-sommes-nous'),
```

Then the view does this:

class AssoView(TemplateView):
hero_image = None
hero_title = None
hero_description = None

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.hero_image is not None:
        context['hero'] = True
        context['hero_image'] = self.hero_image
        context['hero_title'] = self.hero_title or ""
        context['hero_description'] = self.hero_description or ""
    return context
```

and the template base for pages with hero images now just has this line inside a `<style>` block:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("{% static hero_image %}");
```

and some html to position the image and text:

```
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>{{ hero_title }}</h1>
    <p class="hero-description">{{ hero_description }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not cleared please, explain it using some better illustrations.

Comment: Example: to show a specific image if its on a page, if not it should show another image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common pattern and there is no docs on it, because it depends on what the deciding factor is for the image choice:

- Article hero image: will be different for each article, image is uploaded  by author and stored on the "Article" model instance
- Category hero image: different category, different image but items in that category will share the hero image - same thing: image is stored on the category model, but sometimes naming conventions are used with static images (`/static/category/<categoryname>.png`).
- Profile image: different for each user, also uploaded, but bound to a user. Can be integrated on many different pages, for example an author image for a blog or book catalogue

and so on and so on.

Django has all the facilities in place to do this:

- file uploads and corresponding file fields
- views and urls working together that can fetch the correct model instance
- templates that don't care if they render text, html, css, or js

And yes, you would use `<style>` tag in the page html to render the background url. Where that url comes from all depends on that deciding factor.